# Virtuemart 2 / Joomla 2.5 Product Details Links to White Page (error)

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

All of the Product Details pages on my website are returning a blank white page when clicked. Everything has been working just fine for the last couple of months until now. I don't believe I did anything real critical to corrupt it like this. Click any of the "Product Details" links from the page http://lge-ctsmotorsports.com/catalog/apparel-accessories and you will see the error. Unfortunately this is a live site so any help is much appreciated.

I will add that I have error debugging enabled and have edited my configuration.php files to show errors but I can't get any to show. I have also tried to disable plugins that are on those particular pages but non seem to change the outcome.

UPDATE: I was able to see some error logs from GoDaddy that say:
[Mon Nov 26 22:13:08 2012] [error] [client 66.249.75.70] File does not exist: /var/chroot/home/content/40/9930540/html/product_detail.asp
and
[Tue Nov 27 05:17:55 2012] [error] [client 76.94.24.49] File does not exist: /var/chroot/home/content/40/9930540/html/catalog

Comment: Please close your qstn if you get the solution.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't provided enough info here.

The error from GoDaddy sounds like your hoster has been playing around with file permissions, so start there.  Make sure files are 644 and folders 755. Could also be a red herring.

Next you could try install Firebug into Firefox or Chrome or Web Developer tools.  In Firebug, there is a "Console" tab...this will provide you details of the error.

Blank screens normally suggest JavaScript error or no access possibly?

Hope that helps you a little.